# soap ui add wsdl problem

Tags: wsdl, soapui

I am using Websphere Message Broker to create web services. I have two services and two wsdl. One of them has no issues and I am able to add WSDL through soap ui.
The other webservice's wsdl is getting displayed in IE but not able to add it in soap ui

getting
Error loading [http://localhost:7800/SearchRQ.xsd] Unexpected element: CDATA on line 1, column 1

Here is the difference in wsdl from IE of both the wsdl:

Search:

```
<xsd:schema xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
  <xsd:import namespace="http://www.opentravel.org/OTA/2003/05" schemaLocation="SearchRQ.xsd" /> 
  <xsd:import namespace="http://www.opentravel.org/OTA/2003/05" schemaLocation="SearchRS.xsd" /> 
</xsd:schema>
```

DescriptiveInfo:

```
<xsd:schema xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
      <xsd:import namespace="http://www.opentravel.org/OTA/2003/05" schemaLocation="http://localhost:31961/DescriptiveInfo?xsd=xsd1" /> 
</xsd:schema>
<xsd:schema xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
      <xsd:import namespace="http://www.opentravel.org/OTA/2003/05" schemaLocation="http://localhost:31961/DescriptiveInfo?xsd=xsd2" /> 
</xsd:schema>
```

Any idea? Please help me!!!!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I solved the issue. I placed the WSDL in exactly same structure as targetNamespace defined and used targetNamespace in xsd:schema tag similar to wsdl's targetNamespace.